# Is it possible to select an element's attribute with a CSS selector?

Tags: html, css-selectors

I'm looking for a way to use a pure CSS selector (not script)  to select an element's attribute, not the element itself.  I know XPath can do it but can a CSS selector?

Example, given:

```
<img alt="image" src="photo.jpg">
```

Can I get to the `src` attribute with a CSS selector?

Update:

I don't want to set any element's values, I just want to select the text "photo.jpg".

Comment: You can with the CSS `attr()` expression, however, it only works on `content` property for now. What do you need this for? Some context would help.

Comment: No. You can't. But this is an XY Problem, so ask a better question.

Comment: @Aziz I have a web crawler that grabs text from the page and I would like to use CSS to get all images's src attribute.

Comment: @Amit see my demo https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/ns7364ka/

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth why CSS? why not use something like JavaScript or maybe handle it server-side?

Comment: @Amit I tried to resolve the XY problem by removing `with something like: img::src or img@src`.

Comment: Why you can't use some scripts? Don't force a language to do something that it can't or that it'll be more difficult.

Comment: @Aziz Well I could solve my problem easily with XPath, but my question is about CSS.

Comment: That didn't solve anything, you still didn't explain your goal. It's also very unclear what you mean by "select a CSS attribute"

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth The part of your question that is an XY problem is crawling part of a website _with CSS_, not the hypothetical code examples.

Comment: @GilbertoSánchez lol I don't know if CSS can do it or not, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Amit My goal is to use CSS to get to the text "photo.jpg".

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth and then do what exactly? CSS is not designed to "get" values of stuff, it's just a language to style elements.

Comment: No. That's your method, not your goal.

Comment: But if you want to manipulate your images, you can add custom classes, or not? Please explain us what you want to do with all of these.

Comment: @Amit You're right!  Sorry for the confusion, I edited the title from "CSS attribute" to "element's attribute using CSS"

Comment: @Aziz I'm seeing how my question is confusing, I removed the css tag, I just want to know about css-selectors.

Comment: I think OP wants to add padding to element's attribute, would be nice. http://puu.sh/nBW9V/88ec6708bc.png

Comment: @Amit My goal is to use CSS selectors to select the text "photo.jpg".

Comment: @Aziz I don't want to change anything, I just want to know about selectors.  I'm trying to selecct the text "photo.jpg".

Comment: Thanks @Aziz `attr()` was what I was looking for.

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth To be noted though, the `attr()` function is used in pseudo-element and pseudo-element aren't suppose to work with single tag elements like `img`, `input`, etc., still, they do in some browsers, but can suddenly just drop out, so don't rely on it to much.

Comment: So noted, thanks @LGSon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because CSS selectors originated as a fundamental part of CSS, and CSS can only apply styles to elements (since attributes are just element metadata, not standalone objects), CSS selectors cannot match attributes alone within CSS.

But I suspect you're not actually asking about CSS here. You're asking about selectors alone. You're probably using a web automation tool such as Selenium or one of the numerous HTML parsing libraries out there that support either CSS selectors or XPath. Some of these libraries support non-element selectors in the form of pseudo-elements such as `::attr()` (I don't remember which ones), you haven't mentioned which tool you're using so I can't tell you for sure if you could use it. Note that this is *not* the same thing as the CSS `attr()` function mentioned in the comments — that is a CSS function, which is a value, not a selector, and therefore it cannot be used in a selector.

But if your library doesn't have such a feature then you'll need to either select the `img` element directly and query its `src` attribute separately (again, how you do this depends entirely on what you're using, which is why it helps to be specific about this sort of thing), or use XPath if possible.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Tricks has an article that I believe answers your question: 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/

If you are trying to set the value of a certain element attribute using css, I'm pretty certain that is impossible for anything other than the content property.

Comment: Getting the value of an element's attribute is not the same as adding CSS rules based on a specific attribute value...

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not a programming language and can't process data.

Its sole purpose it to tell the browser how a certain element should look like, like in coloring a text red.

To process data in a web page you use javascript, which can make use of CSS rules though, to grab a certain type of elements in a web page, for example this, which will return a list of all elements of type `img`

```
var imglist = document.querySelectorAll('img');
```

Now, having a list you can loop through it and get each `src` like this

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img")).forEach(function(img) {

    var imgsrc = img.src;

    // imgsrc now holds the image url, in your case "photo.jpg"

});
```